# iPhone: Linker Errors with External Files

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors

I've added some files to my project.

The sample code runs elsewhere but when I build my project it returns the errors below.

```
Building target "test" of project "test" with configuration "Debug" - (31 errors)
  Linking /Users/kshan/Desktop/test/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test (31 errors)
     "___gmpn_sub_n", referenced from:
       ___gmpn_sub in CpabeTest.o
     "_bswabe_msk_unserialize", referenced from:
       _GenerateSK in CpabeTest.o
```

Is this a linking problem or something else?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a linker problem. Most likely, you're missing a compiled resource such as a framework.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I don't know which framework I should use because there are no such frameworks that I can use in this code. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you bring in new files to the project? Are you missing an import statement somewhere? It's very hard to advise without knowing what is in your project. I just know the compiler is complaining about missing symbols and I mentioned the most likely source. I can tell you they won't be in one of the default files added automatically to the project.